# How to get filepaths that match a glob without having them on the filesystem

Tags: ruby, glob, fnmatch

I have a list of filepaths relative to a root directory, and am trying to determine which would be matched by a glob pattern. I'm trying to get the same results that I would get if all the files were on my filesystem and I ran `Dir.glob(<my_glob_pattern>)` from the root diectory.

If this is the list of filepaths:

```
foo/index.md
foo/bar/index.md
foo/bar/baz/index.md
foo/bar/baz/qux/index.md
```

and this is the glob pattern:

```
foo/bar/*.md
```

If the files existed on my filesystem, `Dir.glob('foo/bar/*.md')` would return only `foo/bar/index.md`.

The [`glob` docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) mention [`fnmatch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch-3F), and I tried using it but found that the pattern `foo/bar/*.md` was matching `.md` files in any number of nested subdirectories, similar to what `Dir.glob('foo/bar/**/*.md')` would, not just the direct children of the `foo/bar` directory:

```rb
my_glob = 'foo/bar/*.md'

filepaths = [
  'foo/index.md',
  'foo/bar/index.md',
  'foo/bar/baz/index.md',
  'foo/bar/baz/qux/index.md',
]

# Using the provided filepaths
filepaths_that_match_pattern = filepaths.select{|path| File.fnmatch?(my_glob, path)}.sort

# If the filepaths actually existed on my filesystem
filepaths_found_by_glob = Dir.glob(my_glob).sort

raise Exception.new("They don't match!") unless filepaths_that_match_pattern == filepaths_found_by_glob
```

I [incorrectly] expected the above code to work, but `filepaths_found_by_glob` only contains the direct children, while `filepaths_that_match_pattern` contains all the nested children too.

How can I get the same results as `Dir.glob` without having the file paths on my filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flag `File::FNM_PATHNAME` while calling `File.fnmatch` function. So your function call would look like this - `File.fnmatch(pattern, path, File::FNM_PATHNAME)`

You can see examples related to its usage here: https://apidock.com/ruby/File/fnmatch/class

Answer (score -1):

Don't use [`File.fnmatch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch), instead use [`Pathname.fnmatch`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-fnmatch):

```
require 'pathname'

PATTERN = 'foo/bar/*.md'

%w[
  foo/index.md
  foo/bar/index.md
  foo/bar/baz/index.md
  foo/bar/baz/qux/index.md
].each do |p|

  puts 'path: %-24s %s' % [
    p, 
    Pathname.new(p).fnmatch(PATTERN) ? 'matches' : 'does not match'
  ]
end

# >> path: foo/index.md             does not match
# >> path: foo/bar/index.md         matches
# >> path: foo/bar/baz/index.md     matches
# >> path: foo/bar/baz/qux/index.md matches
```

File  assumes the existence of files or paths on the drive whereas  Pathname:

> Pathname represents the name of a file or directory on the filesystem, but not the file itself.

Also, regarding using `Dir.glob`: Be careful using it. It immediately attempts to find every file or path on the drive that matches and returns the hits. On a big or slow drive, or with a pattern that isn't written well, such as when debugging or testing, your code can be tied up for a long time or make Ruby or the machine Ruby's running on go to a crawl, and it only gets worse if you're checking a shared or remote drive. As an example of what can happen, try the following at your command-line, but be prepared to hit <kbd>Cntrl+C</kbd> to regain control:

```
ls /**/*
```

Instead, I recommend using the [Find](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class in the Standard Library as it will iterate over the matches. See that documentation for examples.

Comment: Using `Pathname#fnmatch` just produces the same results as `File#fnmatch`, while I'm looking to get the same results as I would with `Dir#glob`. I can't actually use `Dir#glob`, since I don't actually have the files on the filesystem,  just their paths.